# Running methods inside the view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, login-control

I have this login page i have to make,and it's pretty much done,but i want to implement a first time login password change,and I have a method on my web service to check if it's the first login,and another one to change the password and save it on my database,the thing is,I have the login page with 2 input boxes,one for username,and another one for password,and once i click 'login' i want it to check if it's the first time,and if it is,to change the 2 current input boxes to 'Insert new pwd' and 'Repeat new pwd',but i dont know how to make that happend.I presume it's in the View,but i cant seem to find how anywhere.
This is my view:

```
@model ProjectoEscolas.Models.UserGetInfo
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "LoginEscolas";
 }
<link href="@Url.Content("~/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/Content/login.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginEscolas", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<body>
    <img class="logotipos" src="../Images/logotipos.png"/>
    <div class="login-form">
        <!--<img class="loginimg" src="../Images/logotipos.png">-->
        <h1>Área Privada</h1>
        <p>Para entrar na Área Privada da DGEstE, deverá escrever o Utilizador e a Palavra-Chave das aplicações da <br /> DGEEC(Ex-GEPE)</p>
        <br />            
        <div class="form-group ">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.username, new { placeholder = "Utilizador", @class = "form-control" })
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group log-status">
            @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.password, new { placeholder = "Palavra-Chave", @class = "form-control" })
            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
        </div>
        <span class="alert">Invalid Credentials</span>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="log-btn">           
        @if (ViewBag.Error != null)
        { 
            <h4 style="color:red">@ViewBag.Error</h4>
        }
    </div>
</body>
}
```

And this is the part of the controller im using:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoginEscolas(UserGetInfo user)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error");
        if (user.username == null || user.password == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Insira os campos obrigatórios";
            return View(user);
        }
        else
        {
            if (isValid(Convert.ToInt32(user.username), user.password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.username, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        return View(new UserGetInfo());
    }

    //public ActionResult LogOut()
    //{
    //    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    //    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    //}

    private bool isValid(int username, string password)
    {
        bool isValid;

        int id = Methods.LoginEscolas(username, password);
        if (id != 0)
        {

            Methods.InsertLogs_Escolas(id);
            Debug.WriteLine(id);
            isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isValid = false;
            Debug.WriteLine(id);
            ViewBag.Error = "Insira os seus dados correctamente";
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    public bool haschanged(int username,string password)
    {
        int id = Methods.LoginEscolas(username, password);
        if (!Methods.hasChangedPwd_Escolas(id))
        {
            return false;
        }else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void changePwd(int username,string password,string newPwd)
    {
        int id = Methods.LoginEscolas(username, password);
        Methods.changePwd_Escolas(id, newPwd);
    }
```

Comment: These should be 2 separate methods and views (with separate view models) - a `Register` action and a `Login` action

Comment: @StephenMuecke There won't be a Register,this is for a company,the company users will be given na ID and a password,and when they first log in,they will have to change the password.Sorry for not making it clear

Answer (score 0):

In your LoginEscolas `Action` check your database to see if it is first login. For this, you should have a field in your Users table to save if user has already logged in. If it is first login you can redirect user to another action with different view, lets say `ChangePassword`. Now in `ChangePassword` view you can get new password from user.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginEscolas(UserGetInfo user)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Error");
    if (user.username == null || user.password == null)
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "Insira os campos obrigatórios";
        return View(user);
    }
    else
    {
        if (isValid(Convert.ToInt32(user.username), user.password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.username, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    if(isFirstLogin(Convert.ToInt32(user.username), user.password)))
    {
        setFirstLogin(Convert.ToInt32(user.username));
        return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword");
    }
    return View(new UserGetInfo());
}
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(int userName)
{
    var model = new UserGetInfo {
        username = username
    };
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(int userName, string newPassword)
{
    // Change user password
}
public bool isFirstLogin(int username)
{
    // Check database to see if it is first login
}
public bool setFirstLogin(int username)
{
    // Set FirstLogin to false for this user
}
```